# XSLT removing children from parent dynamically

Tags: xslt

To avoid having to hard code the child element names I want to remove, I'd like to make a dynamic process to remove child elements when a matching parent element name is found.

My XML file:

```
<A>
    <B1>
        <C>C</C>
        <D>D</D>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <MOD>
            <C>C</C>
            <D>D</D>
            <E>E</E>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
        </MOD>
    </B1>
    <B2>
        <C>C</C>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <MOD>
            <C>C</C>
            <D>D</D>
            <E>E</E>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
        </MOD>
    </B2>
    <B3>
        <D>D</D>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <X>X</X>
        <MOD>
            <C>C</C>
            <D>D</D>
            <E>E</E>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
            <X>G</X>
        </MOD>
    </B3>
</A>
```

Desired output:

My XML file:

```
<A>
    <B1>
        <C>C</C>
        <D>D</D>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <MOD>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
        </MOD>
    </B1>
    <B2>
        <C>C</C>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <MOD>
            <D>D</D>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
        </MOD>
    </B2>
    <B3>
        <D>D</D>
        <E>E</E>
        <H>H</H>
        <X>X</X>
        <MOD>
            <C>C</C>
            <F>F</F>
            <G>G</G>
        </MOD>
    </B3>
</A>
```

My XSLT

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Remove child elements but keep parent element with same name -->
    <xsl:template match="C[../ancestor::*/C]"/>
    <xsl:template match="D[../ancestor::*/D]"/>
    <xsl:template match="E[../ancestor::*/E]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think I can combine the remove element code like this

```
<xsl:template match="C|D|E[../ancestor::*/C|D|E]"/>
```

I'm not sure how to start, but I'm thinking the process would have to get the parent node names (C,D,E,H), cycle through the children comparing the parent node name to each child node name.  When a match is found, remove the child element.  Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the explicit rules specifying which elements are to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this stylesheet does what you need. It produces output matching what you say you need by excluding elements that have a parent with a preceding sibling of the same name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
    match="MOD/*[../../* = self::* or preceding-sibling::* = self::*]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<A>
  <B1>
    <C>C</C>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <MOD>
      <C>C</C>
      <D>D</D>
      <E>E</E>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
    </MOD>
  </B1>
  <B2>
    <C>C</C>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <MOD>
      <C>C</C>
      <D>D</D>
      <E>E</E>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
    </MOD>
  </B2>
  <B3>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <X>X</X>
    <MOD>
      <C>C</C>
      <D>D</D>
      <E>E</E>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
      <X>G</X>
    </MOD>
  </B3>
</A>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<A>
  <B1>
    <C>C</C>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <MOD>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
    </MOD>
  </B1>
  <B2>
    <C>C</C>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <MOD>
      <D>D</D>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
    </MOD>
  </B2>
  <B3>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
    <H>H</H>
    <X>X</X>
    <MOD>
      <C>C</C>
      <F>F</F>
      <G>G</G>
    </MOD>
  </B3>
</A>
```

**Explanation:**

- The first template is the well-known [Identity Template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html), which copies all nodes and attributes from the source document to the result document.
- The second template overrides the first and effectively removes all children of `<MOD>` that:

  - have the same name as a previous sibling or
  - have the same name as a sibling of their `<MOD>` parent (an "uncle-or-aunt")

Comment: I think you should reconsider this. The request is _when a matching parent element name_.

Comment: @ABach: What I think `hr_117` means is that it is the *element names* that should be compared.

Comment: @Borodin - you are right; I needed to get more familiar with the XPath spec. I'm going to leave this answer here (since it *does* accomplish the desired output), but I agree that yours is more appropriate.